# How to parse an escaped json string with ansible/jmespath/jq?

Tags: json, ansible, api

I'm using the Ansible module for Bluecat to make an authorized API call to get some information about a subnet. The response looks something like this:

```
"result": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "json": "b'{\"id\":12345,\"name\":\"SUBNET NAME\",\"properties\":\"CIDR=10.2.2.0/24|allowDuplicateHost=enable|pingBeforeAssign=disable|inheritAllowDuplicateHost=true|inheritPingBeforeAssign=true|gateway=10.2.2.1|inheritDNSRestrictions=true|inheritDefaultDomains=true|inheritDefaultView=true|\",\"type\":\"IP4Network\"}\\n'",
        "msg": "",
        "status": 200
}
```

As you can see, all the useful data is in that `json` field, but it's some string literal abomination with escaped quotes and newlines. If I run

```
- debug:
      msg: "{{ result | json_query('json.name') }}"
```

in Ansible, it gives me back the `msg` field instead! I can get the entire `json` field, but not anything inside it. If I tinker with it a little bit and trim the `b` at the beginning, the inner single quotes, and the extra backslash by the newline at the end, then `jq .json | fromjson` parses it correctly. But I'm fairly certain `b''` just means byte encoding and shouldn't break the parsing, but it does. And what's with the double backslashes at the end?

Do I have any options beyond using some `sed` black magic to wipe out all of the escape characters? Why would a web API return a string literal like this?

Comment: That's a Python bytestring-encoded JSON document, JSON-encoded as a value in a JSON document.  Pulling out the Python bytestring (`b'...'`) is easy enough (`jq -r '.result.json'`), but then you would have to find a robust way to decode that into JSON, and my Python-foo is not strong enough for that (`jq` would unfortunately not handle it unless you start doing string manipulations to strip off stuff, which is not the same as decoding).  At the end, pull out the `.name` value from the result as from any ordinary JSON.

Comment: The decoding in python would simply be `str.decode()`, however this keeps the trailing `\\n`

Comment: @Panki The `\\n` would be `\n` at that point (decoded from JSON), so it would be handled correctly.

Comment: @Kusalananda no - compare the output of `a.decode()` and `print(a.decode)`.

Comment: @Panki The output from `jq -r '.result.json'` would be a string starting with `b'{` and ending in `}\n'`. This would be interpreted by Python as a bytestring and it would be decoded into a string (JSON document) ending in a literal newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strip what's outside the braces `{}` and Ansible will parse the dictionary

```yaml
  subnet: "{{ result.json[2:-3] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  subnet:
    id: 12345
    name: SUBNET NAME
    properties: CIDR=10.2.2.0/24|allowDuplicateHost=enable|pingBeforeAssign=disable|inheritAllowDuplicateHost=true|inheritPingBeforeAssign=true|gateway=10.2.2.1|inheritDNSRestrictions=true|inheritDefaultDomains=true|inheritDefaultView=true|
    type: IP4Network
```

Optionally, use a more robust striping. For example, the expression below gives the same result

```yaml
  subnet: "{{ result.json|regex_replace(_regex, _replace) }}"
  _regex: '^.*?\{(.*)\}.*$'
  _replace: '{\1}'
```

If you want to parse the attribute *properties* too, the expression below

```yaml
  subnet_prop: "{{ subnet|combine({'properties': dict(_prop)}) }}"
  _prop: "{{ subnet.properties.split('|')|select|map('split', '=')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  subnet_prop:
    id: 12345
    name: SUBNET NAME
    properties:
      CIDR: 10.2.2.0/24
      allowDuplicateHost: enable
      gateway: 10.2.2.1
      inheritAllowDuplicateHost: 'true'
      inheritDNSRestrictions: 'true'
      inheritDefaultDomains: 'true'
      inheritDefaultView: 'true'
      inheritPingBeforeAssign: 'true'
      pingBeforeAssign: disable
    type: IP4Network
```

---

The boolean values are represented by strings in the dictionary above. If this is a problem replace the *split* filter with *regex_replace* and *from _yaml*. Do it also if the filter *split* is not available

```yaml
  _prop: "{{ subnet.properties.split('|')|
             select|
             map('regex_replace', '^(.*)=(.*)$', '[\\1, \\2]')|
             map('from_yaml')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  subnet_prop:
    id: 12345
    name: SUBNET NAME
    properties:
      CIDR: 10.2.2.0/24
      allowDuplicateHost: enable
      gateway: 10.2.2.1
      inheritAllowDuplicateHost: true
      inheritDNSRestrictions: true
      inheritDefaultDomains: true
      inheritDefaultView: true
      inheritPingBeforeAssign: true
      pingBeforeAssign: disable
    type: IP4Network
```

Comment: This works like a charm, except I'm on too low of a version of ansible to use the `split` fliter. Do you know a different way to split the properties string by the `|` and `=` symbols without using jinja2's split?

Comment: If the filter split is not available replace it with regex_replace and from _yaml. I added an example. This will also solve the *boolean/string* problem, I think.